# portable keylogger for windows 10

Tags: portable, keyboard, keylogger

I should probably say this first, I'm looking for a keylogger that I can put on an external drive to run on my school computer so I can type things without people seeing what I'm typing on my screen. the reason I need it to be portable is that my school laptops won't let you install programs however you can still run portable things like browsers or blender. I don't really care if it's free or not just if it's portable. stealth mode would be preferred but since I'm not trying to catch what the admin password is I don't really care about that.

Comment: Based on your description you are not searching for a pure key-logger but a key-logger that is able to playback the recorded key strokes.

Comment: yes thats what im looking for